# Customizing UUID type for mysql in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I'm porting a java application to jooq.

Currently, I have separate classes for sql to support MySQL, MariaDB, and H2.

I store `UUID` types differently in each because they have varying support. Maria & H2 have UUID data types. MySQL doesn't so I used `BINARY(16)` and convert to/from a UUID myself

I'm not sure how best to handle this with jooq. jooq has a UUID type but for MySQL it creates a `VARCHAR(36)`.

```
create.createTableIfNotExists("users")
    .column("user_uuid", SQLDataType.UUID.notNull())
    .execute();
```

Is there any way I can alter this for mysql so that it uses binary 16 and the `UUID_TO_BIN` functions when queried?

Or do I need to create a copy of this code just for mysql that uses `SQLDataType.BINARY` instead?

It may be worthwhile for me to just accept varchar. This table might have 100k records so the binary 16 was smaller file size than a varchar 36, but it means I'd need to override jooq every time that column is touched.

Comment: (Tangentially related, but 100K records is a wee DB, and UUIDs are 36 hex chars including the dashes--I don't see a compelling reason to do any conversions, just use a UUID. It's a difference of 2M.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is worth optimising on a per dialect basis, then you should indeed use `BINARY` for those database products, and define a table with a dedicated [data type `Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-binding/) that can handle the conversion on a per-dialect basis. That way, you will hardly ever need to touch that column again, it will all be transparent (of course, comparisons and other operators might not work on `BINARY`, which work on `VARCHAR`, but that seems to be OK for you?)